# How to show UserControl in ExpressionBlend 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend-4

I could not understand how to Open MainPage.xaml in ExpressionBlend 4.0 to add some Controls. Nothing is enabled in ExpressionBlend.

The reason is just now I started my First application. Is there any trick? Screenshot is attached for reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance...
Ashok kumar.

Comment: That's curious, I dont see the Design View  or Split screen toggle buttons in the top right corner?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Chris. But, why this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would try hitting F11 to toggle between the views but I don't have answer why the Design/XAML/Split Toggle buttons aren't seen in the top-right corner of the XAML window like one would expect. For now, I would suggest F11 to see if it toggles like it should.